# Question about how identical questions are defined

Tags: support, merged-questions

There is a question that has been asked three times by the same poster with near identical info in the description, but slightly different question title. So my question is, are these three different questions? Or the same question?

- [Computer is totally crashed](https://superuser.com/questions/468854/computer-is-totally-crashed)
- [Computer crashes every 2 to 10 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/465887/computer-crashes-every-2-to-10-minutes)
- [Computer keeps restarting by itself](https://superuser.com/questions/460525/computer-keeps-restarting-by-itself)

Comment: I merged them all together.